# Line breaks in text expansion

Tags: return, newline, autohotkey

I'm a noob but having a tough time with expaning a multiline paragraph
When I use the `` `n `` comand it isn't recognizing it
In msgbox it works fine
Script:

```
::a::
MsgBox, line1 `nline2 `nline 3
```

Produces a message box saying :
line 1
line 2 
line 3

but

```
::a::line 1 `nline 2 `nline 3
```

produces:
line1line2line3

What am I doing wrong??
Thanks

Comment: Your code is working correctly for me.  Have you tried entering this in a few different applications?

Comment: Works fine,here too.  I have to push `a`+ the enter key.  Maybe it's the field you are typing into.  Does it work in notepad?

Comment: I just removed the automatic code placd at the start of the script that is generated when you right click the desktop and select "new authotkey script" and it worked perfectly.

Comment: If you found a solution, please post it as an answer and accept it, so that your question is no longer unanswered.